# What is the limit of the lebesgue integral of the function sequence fn=1/n

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f_n=1/n$ then what is the value of the following limit (Lebesgue integral):  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Rf_n$$

I basically want to prove that a generalisation of the monotone convergence theorem doesn't necessarily work for a decreasing function sequence $f_n\to f$ if  $\int_Rf_1 = \infty$ via example. I've thought of the sequence $f_n=1/n$, since it converges to $f=0$ but I can't prove that the above limit is $\infty$.

Comment: Just compute the integrals.

Comment: I haven't been taught how to as of yet. I know that $\int_Rf_n = \infty$ for every n, but I'm not sure if it works for the limit. Does it?

Comment: $f_n$ are simple functions and thus the integrals are infinite. So it is the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{1}{n}=\dfrac{1}{n}\lambda(\mathbb{R})=+\infty.$$
Thus, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n=+\infty.$$